# Splitting correlation Matrix in 2 Tables

Tags: matrices, split

H! I have a correlation matrix of 14x14 variables - so quite big. 
If I insert my correlation matrix in Latex, and adjust the table to the page size with `begin{adjustbox}{widt=\textwith}`, the table is printed extremely small and not nice to read anymore.

How can i Therefore split the correlation matrix in 2 tables beyond each other? So for example first a table of the first 7x7 variables, and then beyond it the second 7x7 variables?

This is my code of the table:

```
    \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccccccccccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & roap & id & size & age & listed & source & country & gics20 & gics25 & gics30 & gics40 & gics45 & gics50 & gics60 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
roap & $1$ & $0.265$ & $0.360$ & $$-$0.222$ & $0.077$ & $0.202$ & $$-$0.032$ & $$-$0.206$ & $0.268$ & $0.019$ & $$-$0.376$ & $0.310$ & $0.109$ & $$-$0.009$ \\ 
id & $0.265$ & $1$ & $0.385$ & $0.029$ & $$-$0.194$ & $$-$0.036$ & $$-$0.239$ & $$-$0.163$ & $0.114$ & $0.321$ & $$-$0.176$ & $0.102$ & $$-$0.014$ & $$-$0.358$ \\ 
size & $0.360$ & $0.385$ & $1$ & $0.126$ & $0.326$ & $$-$0.121$ & $$-$0.151$ & $$-$0.048$ & $0.138$ & $$-$0.150$ & $$-$0.033$ & $0.466$ & $$-$0.103$ & $$-$0.149$ \\ 
age & $$-$0.222$ & $0.029$ & $0.126$ & $1$ & $0.150$ & $$-$0.362$ & $$-$0.141$ & $$-$0.010$ & $$-$0.110$ & $$-$0.043$ & $0.488$ & $$-$0.103$ & $$-$0.181$ & $$-$0.127$ \\ 
listed & $0.077$ & $$-$0.194$ & $0.326$ & $0.150$ & $1$ & $0.014$ & $$-$0.134$ & $0.013$ & $0.167$ & $$-$0.560$ & $0.211$ & $0.217$ & $0.133$ & $$-$0.002$ \\ 
source & $0.202$ & $$-$0.036$ & $$-$0.121$ & $$-$0.362$ & $0.014$ & $1$ & $0.335$ & $0.164$ & $0.188$ & $$-$0.023$ & $$-$0.561$ & $0.041$ & $0.156$ & $0.100$ \\ 
country & $$-$0.032$ & $$-$0.239$ & $$-$0.151$ & $$-$0.141$ & $$-$0.134$ & $0.335$ & $1$ & $0.216$ & $$-$0.214$ & $0.139$ & $$-$0.104$ & $$-$0.037$ & $$-$0.135$ & $0.141$ \\ 
gics20 & $$-$0.206$ & $$-$0.163$ & $$-$0.048$ & $$-$0.010$ & $0.013$ & $0.164$ & $0.216$ & $1$ & $$-$0.182$ & $$-$0.269$ & $$-$0.202$ & $$-$0.124$ & $$-$0.208$ & $$-$0.097$ \\ 
gics25 & $0.268$ & $0.114$ & $0.138$ & $$-$0.110$ & $0.167$ & $0.188$ & $$-$0.214$ & $$-$0.182$ & $1$ & $$-$0.229$ & $$-$0.172$ & $$-$0.106$ & $$-$0.177$ & $$-$0.083$ \\ 
gics30 & $0.019$ & $0.321$ & $$-$0.150$ & $$-$0.043$ & $$-$0.560$ & $$-$0.023$ & $0.139$ & $$-$0.269$ & $$-$0.229$ & $1$ & $$-$0.253$ & $$-$0.156$ & $$-$0.261$ & $$-$0.122$ \\ 
gics40 & $$-$0.376$ & $$-$0.176$ & $$-$0.033$ & $0.488$ & $0.211$ & $$-$0.561$ & $$-$0.104$ & $$-$0.202$ & $$-$0.172$ & $$-$0.253$ & $1$ & $$-$0.117$ & $$-$0.196$ & $$-$0.091$ \\ 
gics45 & $0.310$ & $0.102$ & $0.466$ & $$-$0.103$ & $0.217$ & $0.041$ & $$-$0.037$ & $$-$0.124$ & $$-$0.106$ & $$-$0.156$ & $$-$0.117$ & $1$ & $$-$0.121$ & $$-$0.056$ \\ 
gics50 & $0.109$ & $$-$0.014$ & $$-$0.103$ & $$-$0.181$ & $0.133$ & $0.156$ & $$-$0.135$ & $$-$0.208$ & $$-$0.177$ & $$-$0.261$ & $$-$0.196$ & $$-$0.121$ & $1$ & $$-$0.094$ \\ 
gics60 & $$-$0.009$ & $$-$0.358$ & $$-$0.149$ & $$-$0.127$ & $$-$0.002$ & $0.100$ & $0.141$ & $$-$0.097$ & $$-$0.083$ & $$-$0.122$ & $$-$0.091$ & $$-$0.056$ & $$-$0.094$ & $1$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

And it is printed as follow: 
[image: Correlation Matrix printed very small]

Any suggestions? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), e.g. what documentclass do you use?, relevant packages, ...?)

Comment: Why not simply rotate the page to a landscape orientation. Depending on your margins and fnz size, you will most likely be able to fit your table into a landscape page (probably with `\small` font size)

Comment: Related: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, using `\adjustbox` does not tend to create usable results -- at least not when trying to create attractive tables. I suggest you do the following instead:

- display the table in landscape format, using the `sidewaystable` environment of the `rotating` package;
- use a `tabular*` environment to ensure that the table fits inside the text block;
- use the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package to align the numbers on their respective explicit or implicit decimal markers; and
- use the macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` -- instead of `\hline` to generate well-spaced horizontal lines. Optionally, use `\addlinespace` directives (also provided by the `booktabs` package) to insert a bit of whitespace after every fifth row or so.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out the intercolumn whitespace amount
\caption{} \label{} 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{14}{S[table-format=-1.3]} } 
\toprule 
 & {roap} & {id} & {size} & {age} & {listed} & {source} & {country} & {gics20} & {gics25} & {gics30} & {gics40} & {gics45} & {gics50} & {gics60} \\ 
\midrule
roap & 1 & 0.265 & 0.360 & -0.222 & 0.077 & 0.202 & -0.032 & -0.206 & 0.268 & 0.019 & -0.376 & 0.310 & 0.109 & -0.009 \\ 
id & 0.265 & 1 & 0.385 & 0.029 & -0.194 & -0.036 & -0.239 & -0.163 & 0.114 & 0.321 & -0.176 & 0.102 & -0.014 & -0.358 \\ 
size & 0.360 & 0.385 & 1 & 0.126 & 0.326 & -0.121 & -0.151 & -0.048 & 0.138 & -0.150 & -0.033 & 0.466 & -0.103 & -0.149 \\ 
age & -0.222 & 0.029 & 0.126 & 1 & 0.150 & -0.362 & -0.141 & -0.010 & -0.110 & -0.043 & 0.488 & -0.103 & -0.181 & -0.127 \\ 
listed & 0.077 & -0.194 & 0.326 & 0.150 & 1 & 0.014 & -0.134 & 0.013 & 0.167 & -0.560 & 0.211 & 0.217 & 0.133 & -0.002 \\ \addlinespace % optional
source & 0.202 & -0.036 & -0.121 & -0.362 & 0.014 & 1 & 0.335 & 0.164 & 0.188 & -0.023 & -0.561 & 0.041 & 0.156 & 0.100 \\ 
country & -0.032 & -0.239 & -0.151 & -0.141 & -0.134 & 0.335 & 1 & 0.216 & -0.214 & 0.139 & -0.104 & -0.037 & -0.135 & 0.141 \\ 
gics20 & -0.206 & -0.163 & -0.048 & -0.010 & 0.013 & 0.164 & 0.216 & 1 & -0.182 & -0.269 & -0.202 & -0.124 & -0.208 & -0.097 \\ 
gics25 & 0.268 & 0.114 & 0.138 & -0.110 & 0.167 & 0.188 & -0.214 & -0.182 & 1 & -0.229 & -0.172 & -0.106 & -0.177 & -0.083 \\ 
gics30 & 0.019 & 0.321 & -0.150 & -0.043 & -0.560 & -0.023 & 0.139 & -0.269 & -0.229 & 1 & -0.253 & -0.156 & -0.261 & -0.122 \\ \addlinespace % optional
gics40 & -0.376 & -0.176 & -0.033 & 0.488 & 0.211 & -0.561 & -0.104 & -0.202 & -0.172 & -0.253 & 1 & -0.117 & -0.196 & -0.091 \\ 
gics45 & 0.310 & 0.102 & 0.466 & -0.103 & 0.217 & 0.041 & -0.037 & -0.124 & -0.106 & -0.156 & -0.117 & 1 & -0.121 & -0.056 \\ 
gics50 & 0.109 & -0.014 & -0.103 & -0.181 & 0.133 & 0.156 & -0.135 & -0.208 & -0.177 & -0.261 & -0.196 & -0.121 & 1 & -0.094 \\ 
gics60 & -0.009 & -0.358 & -0.149 & -0.127 & -0.002 & 0.100 & 0.141 & -0.097 & -0.083 & -0.122 & -0.091 & -0.056 & -0.094 & 1 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the page margins of your document are at most 1" wide, it's actually possible to display the correlation matrix in portrait mode as long as you show just two rather than three digits after the decimal marker. Compared with the code above, all you'd have to do is (a) switch from a `sidewaystable` to a regular `table` environment, and (b) instruct Latex to round the numbers in the 14 data columns to 2 digits; the latter may be achieved easily by running the instruction

```
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2}
```

at the top of the `table` environment. All other elements, such as the use of the `S` column type for data columns and of a `tabular*` environment, needn't be changed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins suitably
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} % <-- new: 'table' instead of 'sidewaystable'
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2} % <-- new
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\caption{\strut} \label{} 

% Change 'S[table-format=-1.3]' to 'S[table-format=-1.2]':
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{14}{S[table-format=-1.2]} } 
\toprule 
 & {roap} & {id} & {size} & {age} & {listed} & {source} & {country} & {gics20} & {gics25} & {gics30} & {gics40} & {gics45} & {gics50} & {gics60} \\ 
\midrule
roap & 1 & 0.265 & 0.360 & -0.222 & 0.077 & 0.202 & -0.032 & -0.206 & 0.268 & 0.019 & -0.376 & 0.310 & 0.109 & -0.009 \\ 
id & 0.265 & 1 & 0.385 & 0.029 & -0.194 & -0.036 & -0.239 & -0.163 & 0.114 & 0.321 & -0.176 & 0.102 & -0.014 & -0.358 \\ 
size & 0.360 & 0.385 & 1 & 0.126 & 0.326 & -0.121 & -0.151 & -0.048 & 0.138 & -0.150 & -0.033 & 0.466 & -0.103 & -0.149 \\ 
age & -0.222 & 0.029 & 0.126 & 1 & 0.150 & -0.362 & -0.141 & -0.010 & -0.110 & -0.043 & 0.488 & -0.103 & -0.181 & -0.127 \\ 
listed & 0.077 & -0.194 & 0.326 & 0.150 & 1 & 0.014 & -0.134 & 0.013 & 0.167 & -0.560 & 0.211 & 0.217 & 0.133 & -0.002 \\ \addlinespace
source & 0.202 & -0.036 & -0.121 & -0.362 & 0.014 & 1 & 0.335 & 0.164 & 0.188 & -0.023 & -0.561 & 0.041 & 0.156 & 0.100 \\ 
country & -0.032 & -0.239 & -0.151 & -0.141 & -0.134 & 0.335 & 1 & 0.216 & -0.214 & 0.139 & -0.104 & -0.037 & -0.135 & 0.141 \\ 
gics20 & -0.206 & -0.163 & -0.048 & -0.010 & 0.013 & 0.164 & 0.216 & 1 & -0.182 & -0.269 & -0.202 & -0.124 & -0.208 & -0.097 \\ 
gics25 & 0.268 & 0.114 & 0.138 & -0.110 & 0.167 & 0.188 & -0.214 & -0.182 & 1 & -0.229 & -0.172 & -0.106 & -0.177 & -0.083 \\ 
gics30 & 0.019 & 0.321 & -0.150 & -0.043 & -0.560 & -0.023 & 0.139 & -0.269 & -0.229 & 1 & -0.253 & -0.156 & -0.261 & -0.122 \\ \addlinespace
gics40 & -0.376 & -0.176 & -0.033 & 0.488 & 0.211 & -0.561 & -0.104 & -0.202 & -0.172 & -0.253 & 1 & -0.117 & -0.196 & -0.091 \\ 
gics45 & 0.310 & 0.102 & 0.466 & -0.103 & 0.217 & 0.041 & -0.037 & -0.124 & -0.106 & -0.156 & -0.117 & 1 & -0.121 & -0.056 \\ 
gics50 & 0.109 & -0.014 & -0.103 & -0.181 & 0.133 & 0.156 & -0.135 & -0.208 & -0.177 & -0.261 & -0.196 & -0.121 & 1 & -0.094 \\ 
gics60 & -0.009 & -0.358 & -0.149 & -0.127 & -0.002 & 0.100 & 0.141 & -0.097 & -0.083 & -0.122 & -0.091 & -0.056 & -0.094 & 1 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion to round the table on 2 digits makes it fit on portrait. I used it just as you, but it does not fit on the printet page. I have a different Geometry: \usepackage[a4paper, footnotesep=0.8cm,width=150mm, top=35mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}, but even if i've tried it with your it does not fit on the textwidth

Comment: @HAL_71 - Indeed, the width of the text block of your document turns out to be narrower than what I had assumed in the second answer. But not all is lost; just add the instruction `\small` immediately after `\begin{table}`, for a 10% linear reduction in font size, and things will work out.